# What's the name of the song in Boku no hero season 3 episode 19 in the minute 19:00 approximately?

Tags: music, my-hero-academia

What's the name of the song in Boku no hero season 3 episode 19 between the minute 18:50 and 19:20 when everyone is helping rescue people?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's called People Always Reaching for the Top;
It's from the OST of Season 2

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i7WnnBS_aIY